# Python, how to interact two different data-frames by lookup or .map

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

## Python, how to interact two different dataframes in one for loop

Hi folks, so I've 2 data-frames.

#### data-frame1 = contains ID an Cost

#### data-frame2 = contains ID

I want to make a for loop that will find the ID and return Cost for data-frame2 as a new column.

#### Issues.. they do not have the some lengh

#### ALso for loop isnot finding the ID's

So they both will have the data, example:

data-frame1 = contains ID and Cost

data-frame2 = contains ID and Cost

```
# data-frame 1

cw.head()

    campaignid  Month   

0   31664745    2019|08 
1   85264521    2019|08 
2   85264521    2019|08 
3   85264521    2019|08 
4   31664745    2019|08 
5   31664745    2019|08 
6   31664745    2019|08 
7   85264521    2019|08 
8   31664745    2019|08 
9   31664745    2019|08 
10  85264521    2019|08 



# data-frame 2

g_spend.head()

    campaignid  cpl

0   31664745    41  
1   85264521    55
```

#### My attempt

```
for c in cw.campaignid:

    if c == range(len(g_spend.campaignid)):
        cw["cpl"] = g_spend.cpl_to_update

    else:
        print("error, bc all values should match")
```

#### Expected result

```
# data-frame 1

cw.head()

    campaignid  Month    cpl

0   31664745    2019|08  41
1   85264521    2019|08  55
2   85264521    2019|08  55
3   85264521    2019|08  55
4   31664745    2019|08  41
5   31664745    2019|08  41
6   31664745    2019|08  41
7   85264521    2019|08  55
8   31664745    2019|08  41
9   31664745    2019|08  41
10  85264521    2019|08  55
```

Comment: If you don't need to use a loop, you could try `merge` with `Pandas`.

Comment: thank you @Hatt but it wouldn't work because they have different length, also I cant merge them for other internal reasons. just need do Lookup

Comment: `merge`, by default, doesn't care about length. It is indeed a good choice for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `campaignid` is unique in `g_spend`, you can use `map` to update the other data:

```
cw['cpl'] = cw['campaignid'].map(g_spend.set_index('campaignid')['cpl'])
```

Output:

```
    campaignid    Month  cpl
0     31664745  2019|08   41
1     85264521  2019|08   55
2     85264521  2019|08   55
3     85264521  2019|08   55
4     31664745  2019|08   41
5     31664745  2019|08   41
6     31664745  2019|08   41
7     85264521  2019|08   55
8     31664745  2019|08   41
9     31664745  2019|08   41
10    85264521  2019|08   55
```

Comment: thanks for helping @Quang, Im getting errors. "Key error for 'cpl' " and "TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
"

Comment: Can you check on `Key error`: your `g_spend.head()` has a `cpl` column.